# Set root view in "inflate" or addView

Tags: android, layout-inflater, android-tablelayout

I wonder what would be the difference between setting  "stockTableLayout" which is TableLayout as a root of "inflated element"

```
View newStockRow = inflater.inflate(R.layout.stock_qoute_row, stockTableLayout);
```

And then modify newStockRow.

VS

```
View newStockRow = inflater.inflate(R.layout.stock_qoute_row, null);
```

modify then newStockRow

and then add it via addView

```
stockTableLayout.addView(newStockRow);
```

Comment: The two are not quite the same. In the first case, `newStockRow` will be `stockTableTableLayout`(nice naming).

Comment: @Luksprog I've changed naming, so edit your comment for clarity, if you could :)

Comment: @Luksprog So the first return, the root element, and the second return the R.layout.stock_qoute_row?

Comment: I can't modify the comment after 5 minutes, but I can delete it if you want. The first version says: inflate this layout file, add it to the `stockTableLayout` and return `stockTableLayout`, the second version says: inflate the layout file and return the root element from that inflated layout file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Luksprog

This method in LayoutInflater class:

```
public View inflate (int resource, ViewGroup root)
```

Returns

**The root View** of the inflated hierarchy. If root was supplied, this is the root View; **otherwise it is the root of the inflated XML file.**

So first way really returns stockTableLayout. Not new Row that I wanted to insert.

But second return the root element of newly created layout from R.layout.stock_qoute_row reference